# assigning values to structure array problem?

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a program to read test file and fill the structure values in a C program.

All other things are OK.

But, when I try to fill the interface value structure, it shows recent `strtok()` value.

The test file looks like,

```
[text file]

TYPE VM vm1
TYPE PM pm1 
NODES 2
APS 2
TYPE wired
NODE-1 NUM_IF 2
NODE-1 IP_ADDR_ETH-0 10.114.12.1
NODE-1 IP_ADDR_ETH-1 10.114.12.2
NODE-1 VM_ID 1
NODE-1 MEM_SIZE 512
NODE-1 OS FEDORA

NODE-2 NUM_IF 3
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-0 10.114.14.1
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-1 10.114.14.2
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-2 10.114.14.3
NODE-2 VM_ID 2
NODE-2 MEM_SIZE 1GB
NODE-2 OS CENTOS
NODE-2 10.114.12.7


[/textfile]
```

My code is,

```
/*
 * configparse1.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 24, 2011
 *      Author: nco_user
 */
/*
 * parsetest1.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 24, 2011
 *      Author: sjayaram
 */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void stcpy(char *str1, char *str2);

/* Common information structure. */
typedef struct CINFO {
    int num_nodes;
    int num_aps;

}cinfo;

/* Interfaces definition structure. */
typedef struct INTERFACE {
    char *ip_addr;
    char *netmask;
    char *gateway;
} if_val1;

/* Node information structure. */
typedef struct node {
    char name[20];
    char val[20];
    char OS[10];
    int vm_id;
    int num_if;
    //char *OS;
    if_val1 node_if[10];
    long int memsize;
}node1;


/* File pointer .*/
FILE *f;


int main()
{
    int j,k;
    char string[1000], seps[] = " \n,( )-";
    char *p;
    char s[10];
    int i=0;

    node1 nodeuse;
    node1 node1[20];
    //if_val1 if_val[10];
    cinfo commontoolinfo;
    if_val1 zero_ifintf;


    //int a;
    f=fopen("test.config","r");
    if(!f)
    return 1;

    memset(&zero_ifintf,0,sizeof(zero_ifintf));
    while(fgets( string, sizeof(string)-1, f) != NULL)
    {
        /* Break into tokens. */
        p = string;
        p = strtok( string, seps ); /* Find first token*/
        //printf("Beginning tok=%s\n",p);
        memset(nodeuse.name,0,sizeof(nodeuse.name));
        memset(nodeuse.val,0,sizeof(nodeuse.val));
        while( p != NULL )
        {
            printf("Token: %s\n", p);

            //printf("Hello-1 \n");
            /* Getting node and APs value. */
            if(strcmp(p,"NODES")==0)
            {
                int a;
                a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
                commontoolinfo.num_nodes=a;
                //printf("Hello-2 \n");
                //commontoolinfo.num_aps=0;
                //printf("Hello-1 \n");
            }

            if(strcmp(p,"APS")==0)
            {
                int num_aps;
                num_aps=(atoi)(strtok(NULL,seps));
                commontoolinfo.num_aps=num_aps;
                //printf("Hello-3 \n");
            }

            if(strcmp(p,"TYPE")==0)
            {
                p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                printf("type name= %s \n",p);
                strcpy(s,p);
                //printf("S= %s \n",s);
                //printf("Hello-4 \n");
            }

            if (strcmp(p,"NODE")==0)
            {
                int a;
                //p1= (char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
                a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
                //int i;
                //printf("a=%d \n",a);

                switch (a)
                {
                case 1:
                {
                    //printf("Hello-5 \n");
                    //i=0;
                    //printf("hello 5-1\n");
                    p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                    //printf("hello 5-2\n");
                    if(strcmp(p,"NUM_IF")==0)
                    {
                        //printf("hello 5-21\n");
                        int a;
                        a = (atoi)(strtok( NULL, seps ));
                        //printf("hello 5-22\n");
                        node1[i].num_if=a;
                        printf("************* NUM_OF_INTF=%d**********/n/n",node1[i].num_if);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(p,"VM_ID")==0)
                    {
                        int a;//=malloc(sizeof(2*int));
                        node1[i].vm_id=0;
                        a = (atoi) (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
                        //memset(node1[i].vm_id,0,sizeof(node1[i].vm_id));
                        node1[i].vm_id=a;
                        printf("VM-ID=%d \n",node1[i].vm_id);
                        //printf("Hello-7 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p,"MEM_SIZE")==0)
                    {

                        //long int a = malloc(sizeof(long int));
                        int a;
                        a = (atoi) (strtok(NULL,seps));
                        node1[i].memsize=0;
                        //memset(node1[i].memsize,0,sizeof(node1[i].memsize));
                        node1[i].memsize = a;
                        printf("mem-size=%ld\n",node1[i].memsize);
                        //free(a);
                        //printf("Hello-8 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p, "OS")==0)
                    {
                        printf("Hello-9 \n");
                        //char *s;
                        char *s;// = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
                        //node1[i].OS = malloc(sizeof(char*));
                        s = strtok(NULL,seps);
                        printf("********* S = %s **********\n\n",s);
                        //memset((char*)node1[i].OS,0,sizeof(node1[i].OS));
                        //node1[i].OS =s;
                        //printf("test1 ----\n");
                        strcpy((node1[i].OS),s);
                        //free(s);

                        printf("OS type:%s\n",(node1[i].OS));

                        printf("Hello-10 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p,"IP_ADDR_ETH")==0)
                        {

                            printf("--------------hi1 \n");
                            int comp,a;
                            printf("------------hi2 \n");
                            a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/

                            if(a < (node1[i].num_if))
                            {
                                printf("-------------hi3 \n");
                                p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                                (node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr)= p;
                                //strcpy((node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr),p);
                                printf("Node[%d] interface-eth[%d] address=%s \n\n", i,a,(node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr) );
                            }

                            printf("---------------------hi4 \n");
                        }
                    i++;
                }


                //printf("Hello-11 \n");
                break;

                case 2:
                {
                    i=1;

#if 0
                    p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                    memset(node1[i].name,0,sizeof(p));
                    //printf("test11 \n");
                    //memset(node1[i].OS,0,sizeof(p));
                    //printf("test12 \n");
                    strcpy(node1[i].name,p);
                    //printf("test4 \n");
                    printf("node1[i]->name= %s \n",node1[i].name);
                    //printf("test5 \n");
                    //printf("Hello-12 \n");
                    //printf("2.OS type:%s\n",node1[0].OS);
                    break;
#endif
                    //printf("hello 5-1\n");
                    p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                    //printf("hello 5-2\n");
                    if(strcmp(p,"NUM_IF")==0)
                    {
                        //printf("hello 5-21\n");
                        int a;
                        a = (atoi)(strtok( NULL, seps ));
                        //printf("hello 5-22\n");
                        node1[i].num_if=a;
                        printf("************* NUM_OF_INTF=%d**********/n/n",node1[i].num_if);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(p,"VM_ID")==0)
                    {
                        int a;//=malloc(sizeof(2*int));
                        node1[i].vm_id=0;
                        a = (atoi) (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
                        //memset(node1[i].vm_id,0,sizeof(node1[i].vm_id));
                        node1[i].vm_id=a;
                        printf("VM-ID=%d \n",node1[i].vm_id);
                        //printf("Hello-7 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p,"MEM_SIZE")==0)
                    {
                        //long int a = malloc(sizeof(long int));
                        int a;
                        a = (atoi) (strtok(NULL,seps));
                        node1[i].memsize=0;
                        //memset(node1[i].memsize,0,sizeof(node1[i].memsize));
                        node1[i].memsize = a;
                        printf("mem-size=%ld\n",node1[i].memsize);
                        //free(a);
                        //printf("Hello-8 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p, "OS")==0)
                    {
                        printf("Hello-9 \n");
                        //char *s;
                        char *s;// = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
                        //node1[i].OS = malloc(sizeof(char*));
                        s = strtok(NULL,seps);
                        printf("********* S = %s **********\n\n",s);
                        //memset((char*)node1[i].OS,0,sizeof(node1[i].OS));
                        //node1[i].OS =s;
                        //printf("test1 ----\n");
                        strcpy(node1[i].OS,s);
                        //free(s);

                        printf("OS type:%s\n",node1[i].OS);

                        printf("Hello-10 \n");
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(p,"IP_ADDR_ETH")==0)
                    {

                        printf("--------------hi1 \n");
                        int comp,a;
                        printf("------------hi2 \n");
                        a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
                        printf("A is value=%d \n\n ",a);
                        if(a < (node1[i].num_if))
                        {
                            printf("-------------hi3-0 \n");
                            p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                            (node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr)= p;
                            //strcpy((node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr),p);
                            printf("-------------hi3-1 \n");
                            printf("Node[%d] interface-eth[%d]address=%s \n\n", i,a,(node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr) );
                        }

                        printf("---------------------hi4 \n");
                        printf("*************8 Node[%d] interface-eth[%d]address=%s \n\n", i,0,(node1[i].node_if[0].ip_addr) );
                        printf("*****************8 Node[%d] interface-eth[%d]address=%s \n\n", i,1,(node1[i].node_if[1].ip_addr) );
                        printf("*****************8 Node[%d] interface-eth[%d]address=%s \n\n", i,2,(node1[i].node_if[2].ip_addr) );
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                break;

                default:
                    break;
                    //printf("Hello-13 \n");
                }



#if 0
                    if(strcmp(p,"1")==0)
                    {
                        node1 node1[20];
                        i=0;
                        p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                        memset(node1[i].name,0,sizeof(p));
                        strcpy(node1[i].name,p);
                    }
#endif
                    //free(p1);
                    //printf("VM NAME: %s \n",nodeuse.name);
                    //printf("test1 ********** \n");
                    //printf("Hello-15 \n");
            }

            //printf("Hello-16 \n");

            p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
            //printf("Hello-2 \n");
        }  //end of inner while
        //printf("Hello-17 \n");
    }   //end of first while



    printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",1,0,(node1[0].node_if[0].ip_addr));
    printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",1,1,(node1[0].node_if[1].ip_addr));
    printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,0,(node1[1].node_if[0].ip_addr));
    printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,1,(node1[1].node_if[1].ip_addr));
    printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,2,(node1[1].node_if[2].ip_addr));



    printf("Hello-18 \n");
    for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
    {
        //printf("test11 ********** \n");
        printf("VM ip: %s \n",node1[j].name);
    }


    //printf("test2 ********** \n");
    for(k=0;k<commontoolinfo.num_nodes;k++)
    {
        int comp;
        printf("NODE%d number of interfaces=%d \n",(k+1),node1[k].num_if);

        for(comp=0;comp < node1[k].num_if;comp++)
        {
            printf("Node[%d] of Interface ETH-[%d] IP ADDR=%s \n\n",(k+1),comp,node1[k].node_if[comp].ip_addr);

        }
        printf("NODE%d VM_ID=%d\n",(k+1),node1[k].vm_id);
        printf("NODE%d MEM_SIZE=%ld\n",(k+1),node1[k].memsize);
        printf("NODE%d OS=%s\n",(k+1),node1[k].OS);
    }

    fclose(f); /* Close opening file pointer. */

    printf("End of program \n");
    return 0;

}


void stcpy(char *to, char *from)
{
     while(*from)
          *to++ = *from++;
      *to = '\0'; /* null terminates the string */
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: Please reduce the problem by minimizing the source code and test data which is needed to reproduce the problem. That way, people don't have to waste time (and brain cells) on understanding irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
commontoolinfo.num_nodes=a; 
use strcpy(commontoolinfo.num_nodes,a)
```

...because `strtok` will return `char * value`...